# Postgresql order by column that not in group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I need to get movies with fresh series first.

In rails I have:

```
l, o = 30, 0
Movie.joins(:series).order("series.created_at DESC").group("movies.id").limit(l).offset(o)
```

It translate to:

```
SELECT  "movies".* 
FROM "movies" INNER JOIN "series" ON "series"."movie_id" = "movies"."id"
GROUP BY movies.id
ORDER BY series.created_at DESC
LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

But I have error message

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:
column "series.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used
in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ..._id" = "movies"."id" GROUP BY movies.id  ORDER BY series.cre...
                                                             ^
```

And OFFSET working very strange, sometimes he duplicate results.

How can I fix this without using sql? Would it work in MySQL?

In Pg I have many little problems like this, how do u think if I change it to MySQL would it work better?

PS: In sqlite it works file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use agg max if you want fresh one `Movie.joins(:series).order("max(series.created_at) DESC").group("movies.id").limit(l).offset(o)`

Without aggregation this query does not know what series to order - it s not a pgsql or mysql issue.

In posgres you have more possibilities for aggregations